# How to not load translation namespace by default on init using i18next?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have two translation files in the `locales/{{lng}}` directories. They are `translations1.json` and `translations2.json`. I am also using backend in the `i18next.init` as follows

```
backend: {
   loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json
}
```

I pass in the specific namespace as an argument to `useTranslation` and that namespace does load, however I am still seeing a failed get request to `localhost:3000/locales/en/translation.json` when the web app first loads. I do not want this request to be made, or any default request to be made.

I tried adding `defaultNS: false` in the `init`. I was expecting that this would mean a call is not made to the backend until a specific namespace is passed in. However this did not change anything.

Edit: I have found one solution, which is to include `ns: []` in `init`.